# Vaadin Create <div>simple text</div> with no styles or classes?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is this possible? Do I need to create custom componant? I simple want to create a div that just hold text and be able to change the text programatically.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's your use case? Why you cannot use a `Label`?

Comment: It involves a bit more overriding on my part. I was hoping for option with a empty div. for a clean slate to work on

Comment: For example `label.setPrimaryStyleName("foobar")` replaces Label's standard `v-label` style name with `foobar` in the `Label`. Doesn't remove all style names from the Label, and anyways there will be cascading style names from your application's Vaadin theme.

Comment: Perfect! SetPrimaryStyleName I think is going to help with what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the `v-label` style name from your `Label`, you could say

```
label.setPrimaryStyleName("foobar");
```

It replaces the `v-label` style name with `foobar`.